# Конкуренция средств выразительности

Tags: метафора

> Быть может, книги помогут тебе взлететь".

Это задание из демоверсии ОГЭ по русскому.

Кто может объяснить, почему тут видят **метафору**?

Для меня здесь чистой воды **олицетворение**:
"книги помогают взлететь" - человек помогает взлететь.

Comment: олицетворение, если бы главным было книги, но тут художественное слово, это не книги, а взлететь. Взлететь - в смысле не полететь по небу, а как бы "взлететь". Книги помогут "взлететь" - метафора. А олицетворение это ближе к: мои лучшие друзья - это книги, книги учат меня, поддерживают в трудную минуту, я помню все их имена... - что-то такое.

Answer (score 2):

Известная метафора: *взлететь **на вершину славы***

Здесь ***взлететь*** – добиться успеха, реализовать планы, стать достойным человеком. ***Человек** может взлететь, как **птица**.*

Взлететь кверху (= подняться) могут и **неодушевленные** предметы, например цены. Это значение есть в словаре (разг.), языковая метафора.  Пример: *Рекордным для таких сделок стал 1981 г., когда **процентные ставки** резко взлетели вверх.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

*Книги помогут* – **олицетворение**? Но это значение есть **в словаре**.Тогда нельзя считать тропом (олицетворением).

И тогда : *Книги помогут взлететь* – **метафора.**

Из словаря: **ПОМОЧЬ**, 2. Оказать нужное действие. Лекарство помогло. Курсы интенсивного обучения помогли овладеть языком. Никакие разговоры не помогли (оказались бесполезными, бесплодными).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Вообще говоря, метафоричность  зависит **от контекста.** Вот прочитаю я книги о том, как зарабатывать деньги, как стать влиятельным и успешным, применю знания на практике и добьюсь желаемого – чем **не полет** к вершинам богатства и власти. Это **метафора.**

Но можно читать и другие книги, которые помогут человеку стать личностью, осознать свое предназначение – это уже полет к **духовным** вершинам. И это тоже **метафора**.

*Как **крылья** помогают птице **взлететь**, так **книга** помогает **взлететь** человеку.*

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

[https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/взлететь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)

[https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/взлететь+на+вершину](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)

**[Все средства художественной выразительности для ЕГЭ. №26](https://dzen.ru/a/YBKCnItZX2GY5Xnc)**

Метафора – это троп, скрытое сравнение. В отличие от обычного сравнения, когда явно сопоставляются по сходству два предмета, в метафоре один из них скрыт, что и создает многозначность и образность. Проще говоря, метафора – это то, чего не может быть. Флейта водосточных труб, половодье чувств, сквозняк в голове.

Олицетворение – это троп, подвид метафоры, когда что-то неживое наделяется свойствами живого организма. Ветер выл, кричал и плакал.

Comment: Так это все-таки олицетворение или метафора?

Comment: Книги помогут - олицетворение (подвид метафоры),  помогут взлететь - метафора, книги помогут взлететь  олицетворение + метафора.  То  есть в целом предложение метафорического характера.

Comment: Олицетворение не совсем подвид метафоры, олицетворение - это одушевление или всякий морфизм, а метафора - это перенос состояния или действия на что-то иное, сравнение с чем-то иным. Метафора про глаголы больше, а олицетворение про существительные и тп. И тут хитрый момент, так как речь то не про книги, а про "тебе взлететь". И книги помогут - это не совсем олицетворение. Например: топор поможет срубить дерево, а каска сбережёт голову. Это вряд ли олицетворение, это скорее про функциональность вещи. А вот: пила весело запела, топор устал рубить и затупился - это уже олицетворение.

Comment: Я дополнила ответ. Помочь могут и неодушевленные предметы, в том числе книги (по словарю). Тогда это не олицетворение. Получается, что предложение в целом – это МЕТАФОРА.

Comment: Могут, но это не всегда олицетворение, я написал подробный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже вижу здесь **олицетворение**.
**ОЛИЦЕТВОРЕНИЕ** - вид тропа: изображение неодушевленных предметов, при котором они наделяются свойствами живых существ (даром речи, способностью мыслить, чувствовать, переживать, **действовать**), уподобляются живому существу.
Например: "О чем ты воешь, ветр ночной? // О чем так сетуешь безумно?" (Ф.И. Тютчев); "Сквозь волнистые туманы // Пробирается луна" (А.С. Пушкин). Разновидность метафоры.

---

Метафоричность складывается из переноса значения. В чем здесь перенос, в том, что книги научат тебя жить? Слишком сложно для **метафоры**, **олицетворение** в любом случае стоит ближе к истине: книги, материальный предмет, подобный человеку, совершают действия.

---

Таким образом, считать данную фразу **только метафорой** не совсем **уместно**.

Answer (score 0):

Ладно, напишу.

В общем метафора - это больше про состояния, глаголы, процессы, их перенос, перенос физического.

А олицетворение - это про перенос духовного и всяких чувств, одушевление.

> ОЛИЦЕТВОРЕНИЕ - персонификация, присущее мифопоэтическому сознанию свойство перенесения на неодушевлённые вещи и явления черт живых
> существ: человеческих (антропоморфизм, антропопатизм) или животных
> (зооморфизм), а также наделение животных качествами человека.

> МЕТАФОРА — вид тропа (см.), употребление слова в переносном значении; словосочетание, характеризующее данное явление путем
> перенесения на него признаков, присущих другому явлению (в силу того
> или иного сходства сближаемых явлений), к-рое так. обр. его замещает.

То есть метафора не имеет цели "улучшения" основной природы, она скорее упрощает, а олицетворение скорее возвеличивание природы чего-то через одушевление вещей или очеловечивание животных, наделение животных чувствами, пониманием, а вещей эмоциональностью и тп.

Поэтому я бы не путал метафору и олицетворение. Хотя, метафора - это более общее понятие, и иногда могут сказать, мол, это метафорически, но это скорее культурное веяние то ли материализма, то ли рационального прагматизма. Проблема в том, что материалисты склонны к механизации явлений и, скажем, живые организмы могут быть рассмотрены как механизмы - например насекомые, это сложные но биомеханизмы, но душой они их не наделяют, нет души. А идеалисты, особенно современные идеалисты, же склонны одушевлять, поэтому это отдельная тема, причем именно олицетворение не было распространено в той же Древней Греции, и их басни, например Эзопа (которые, кстати говоря, в прозе), именно метафоричны, и в них люди скорее отождествлялись с животными или вещами по признакам. А вот басни Крылова - это уже олицетворение, потому что животные и их поведение, часто звериное поведение, сравнивается с человеческим - а это совсем наоборот. Метафора более рациональна, хотя она может быть поэтична и пафосна, либо насмешлива. То есть в метафоре все греческое: комедии, трагедии прочий эпос. А вот олицетворение - это народное творчество, нерациональное, через чувство, и особняком олицетворение драматическое - басни Крылова, с социальными лицами животных.

Ну и я бы поделил метафору как явления, процессы, ну и в основном глаголы и понятия связанные с глаголами. А олицетворение - это существительные, чувственность и эмоциональность. Метафора пафосна, а олицетворение драматично.

Переходя к примеру:

Быть может, книги помогут тебе взлететь.

Книги помогут - если это и олицетворение, то очень вырожденное. А вот: книжечка, помоги! - это олицетворение, так как обращение к одушевленности книги. Тем более что тут обращение кого-то к кому-то, так что это помощь кого-то через предмет, по средствам предмета. Средство - это уже не что-то отдельное, а часть того, кто подал идею. Кроме того, говорящий человек отказывается от собственного я, говоря: быть может. То есть оно случится само по себе, помощь случится сама по себе - вероятное событие. А сказал бы: спроси у книги, она ответит тебе - тогда да, олицетворение.

А вот *взлететь* - тут явно перенос восприятия на физическое явление + пафос полета, то есть метафора 100%.

Так что ответ: метафора.

То есть: метафора - это упрощение до качества и перенос качества на другое явление, но часто с сохранением пафоса, либо со смехом - разрушением пафоса собственного ложного восприятия; а олицетворение - это чувственная персонификация и/или эмоциональность + возвышение / либо с осмеянием сравнения и утверждение за счёт принижения другого. Мать качает малыша на волнах любви - метафора; волны обняли ласково и по-матерински  - олицетворение. Катись колбаской по малой Спасской - метафора, как и большинство пословиц и поговорок; ну а осмеяния полно у Крылова, когда каждый думает, какая, мол, тупая обезьяна, лиса и тп., хаха, я не такой, я человек же и тп. - то есть пытается разрушить олицетворение и тем самым откреститься от ошибок и утвердиться за счёт принижения другого. Метафора - собственно страдание и собственный смех; олицетворение - страдание другого, смех над другим.

Добавлю мяса:

В общем все эти тропы-фигуры речи берут начало от прогимнасматы Progymnasmata(προγυμνάσματα) - сборник упражнений по риторики, который состоял из:

> Этот список из 14 упражнений взят из справочника прогимнасмат,
> написанного Афонием из Антиохии, риториком четвертого века.
>
> басня Fable (μῦθος) - > Басни Эзопа, басни в прозе -> метафора
>
> рассказ, пересказ Narration (διήγημα) - одиночное повествования, не путать с нарративом, как это делает педивикия! Narration - близкое к документальному, но с возможным сохранением пафоса, в то время как Narrative - это версия, наполненная вымыслами, субъективными оценками и тп. Narration - рассказ, narrative - байка.
>
> анекдот Anecdote (χρεία) -> Про Штирлица, хотя в оригинале, это не совсем выдуманные истории.
>
> что-то похожее на пословицы, только банальнее Maxim (γνώμη) - Plausible: ‘Each man is like those in whose company he delights.’ ~ Каждый кулик своё болото хвалит.
>
> навет (обвинение) Refutation (ἀνασκευή) - история с выводом, что, мол, вот это не правильно потому что, чтоб им пусто было этим аморальным чертям! Let there be an end to the poets, lest I seem to be decrying them.
>
> похвала (защита) Confirmation (κᾰτᾰσκευή) - рассказывается таже самая история, но в процессе делается вывод, что как это хорошо и какие мол они молодцы, поэты - великие люди. For these reasons I admire the poets, and for this reason I honour due measure. Такие приёмы можно встретить во время свадебных обрядов, расхваливают жениха, а со стороны невесты наоборот его заслуги пытаются принизить, но не оскорбляют, чтобы вытянуть побольше денег, игра такая.
>
> общие рассуждения Commonplace (κοινός τόπος) - более циничное рассуждение, с плюсами и минусами того или иного явления, без выражения собственного отношения. - эти три упражнения думаю, базовые для всяких юристов-адвокатов.
>
> похвала, поздравительные речи Encomium (enkōmion) - Мы строили строили и наконец построили! Ура нам! Всякие речи на мероприятиях по факту заслуг, достижений.
>
> обвинение Ivective (ψόγος) - прокуроры и тп.
>
> сравнение, противопоставление Comparison (σύνκρίσις)

> что-то между одушевлением и одержимостью Characterisation / Personification (ēthopoeia)

В общем, скажем, есть Геракл, но он умер, нужно представляя его образ, придумать, что он бы мог сказать про это дело. Или есть образ бога, и нужно придумать его рассуждения, соображение на этот счет. Однако, это не совсем олицетворение и прозопопея, так как Геракл - это человеко-бог, боги тоже как суперлюди, а вот в какой момент вещи и звери уподобляются людям - это сложно сказать. Но тем не менее, олицетворение - это думать как персонаж, размышлять через образ чужого бытия, представляя себя другим, не собой. В баснях Эзопа нет момента отчуждения, в них есть момент, когда хочется быть похожем на героя басни, брать пример. Но вот не скажешь же, бери пример со шкафа, хотя: порхай как бабочка, жаль как пчела - это сравнение и метафора. "Characterisations may be pathetic, ethical or mixed. The pathetic are those which
indicate emotion at every point" - **эмоциональный момент, сожаление, трогательность и отчуждение с ними связанное это ключевое в олицетворении.**
И еще интересный момент.  Instead of heads, you will divide into the
three times—present, past and future. То есть деление на прошлое-настоящее-будущее тоже связано с этой формой размышления. В то время как метафора - не имеет временного интервала, так как миф вечен.
То есть: вот тебе книга - лети. Все, ты берешь книгу и полетел, даже можно не читать, а воображать себя умницей. А если "книжка порвалась ей больно заклей" - то это олицетворение, сейчас - ей больно, но если заклеишь - то боль пройдет и она будет обычной книгой, а не одушевленной фантасмагорией. Олицетворение имеет стремление к экзорцизму, так как "ожившая" книга - это не нормально. Метафора же наоборот - это гипер реализм, некий совершенный мир в противопоставлении физическому.

> описание, изложение Description (ἔκφρᾰσις) - описание какого-то объекта, явления, наблюдение, важный момент конкретика.

> тезис, аргументация Thesis(θέσις) - Thesis: should one marry? приведите аргументы за и против на отстраненную тему.
>
> предложение к закону Proposal of Law (νόμος εϊσφόρα) - ну это юридические штуки типа трактовок и комментариев к законам, но не законченные, а дискуссионные.

[Оригинальный текст Aphthonius Progymnasmata на английском](https://people.umass.edu/dfleming/E388%20Aphthonius%20Progymnasmata.pdf)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148497/discussion-on-answer-by----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @Буратино  Дискуссия продолжается...  Я думаю, что было бы интересно привести примеры предложений, где книга действительно является олицетворением или метафорой.  (Хорошо бы в новом ответе, чтобы было видно всем, да и голосование за него возможно.)  В соответствии со словарем (для глагола помочь), книга вообще может не иметь значение переноса, но может при этом действовать  http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=помочь&all=x

Comment: @Sharon я привел свои примеры, которые сам выдумал), дело же не в том, чтобы найти и сделать по шаблону, а в том, чтобы понять принцип - основу того, почему это олицетворение или метафора. В данном изложении мне видится только одно слабое звено - это почему прозопопея тоже самое, что этопойя. Вот тут увы я не могу сказать, просто так пишут, но я также исхожу из собственного понимания процесса развития данных процессов в литературно-речевом творчестве. А если опираться на логику этих упражнений по риторике, можно понять разницу в типах мышления что ли.

Comment: У вас очень интересное объяснение, но школьники  ничего этого не поймут.  Они учатся именно на шаблонах, вот и учителю приходится использовать такой же метод объяснения. Было бы очень хорошо, если вы, учитывая свое понимание, составили им такие учебные шаблоны.  Если это, конечно, возможно.  Вы уже что-то такое говорили: Книжечка, помоги. Книга - мой друг.  Но это все в комментариях, в развернутом ответе...  А для шаблонов нужен бы отдельный ответ.  Тем более что дискуссия продолжается...

Comment: То есть с одной стороны метафорическое(мифическое) восприятие - логические ассоциации близкие к метафизике и прозе, а есть через чувственно-ассоциативное, поэтическое. И еще особняком стоит аллегория. У аллегории есть символ, с часто тайным смыслом, неочевидным. Что интересно, тут аллегории нет. Аллегория это: Гефест это огонь, а огонь это Гефест. То есть имеет место быть референс с одного понятия на другое, с общего на частное, предмет, объект. Деперсонификация?

Comment: @Sharon школьники в своем большинстве учатся по шаблонам, потому что их так учат. Ну пусть учатся, школьники не должны диктовать то, как я должен объяснять, прежде всего себе, что-то, как я должен это понимать. И опять же я вы вожу принцип: метафора тяготеет к отстраненности и переносу качеств, свойств объектов, явлений, процессов; а олицетворение всегда находится в чувственной сфере восприятия, причем связанно с чувствами ДРУГОГО. Метафора - это я воспринимаю так, а олицетворение - мне кажется, что что-то или кто-то другой воспринимает эти обстоятельства вот так.

Comment: И да, у школьников как у детей есть проблемы с восприятием абстракции лет до 12+/-, просто потому что личности у ребенка нет, есть характер - индивидуальность. То есть ребенок может только олицетворять, а метафору он не понимает практически совсем. Метафора абстрактна, это чисто восприятие, с минимумом эмоциональности. Короче это вторая сигнальная по Павлову. Поэтому и взрослые не все метафору воспринимают - не научились. А олицетворение и религиозные аллегории - пожалуйста. С другой стороны образы по настоящему полные содержат в себе много чего, но это не повод пытаться понять.

Comment: Метафора максимально неформальна, так как абстрактна и научить на шаблоне метафоре нельзя, получился или аллегория или олицетворение.)))

Comment: Жаль, а я думала, что можно.  Шаблоны нужны не только ребенку, но и УЧИТЕЛЮ, который учит ребенка. Сам-то он, может, и понимает, а объяснить как.  Практика проверяет любую теорию (мне так кажется).

Comment: @Sharon ну все не так сложно, вы читали басни Эзопа? И жизнеописание Эзопа. Просто вот дают детям читать книжки, даже не Эзопа, хотя это маленькая книжечка, а Пушкина, Гоголя. А ребенок не читает, а читает нарратив - краткое содержание, шаблон, причем кривой. И как о чем-то говорить, если в голове только шаблон и то сколько запомнилось?

Comment: Слышала (греческого не знаю))... Что-то вроде этого  https://rustih.ru/ezop/   Действительность заставляет. Дети ходят в школу, экзамены сдают пусть  хотя бы сначала шаблоны выучат.  А мыслителями (вроде Эзопа) станут позже))

Comment: У него есть басни, а есть жизнеописание - это набор перлов вперемежку с баснями. Читайте) Еще Золотой Осёл Апулея - это вообще гремучая смесь символизма+олицетворения и метафоры. Читал охотно Апулея, а Цицерона не читал (А. С. Пушкин). Я не так много читал, даже мало, но эти книжки перевернули моё представление о литературе. Апулей - это просто ключ к пониманию целого ряда аллегорий человек-животное ~ человеческое животное, что есть человек в конце концов.

Comment: Осел-философ)... А Эзоп vs Крылов - и получается срачь 16 века Лессинга, который тоже басни писал, но в прозе и только в прозе, и говорил что вообще те кто пишет басни в стихах - это фигляры, так мол нельзя. Поэтому вся эта компания, которая друг у друга басни переписывала Лафонтен-Крылов и иже с ними, ну и у Эзопа они сдули почти все, это мол не творцы, а черт знает что и ничего они не понимают в метафоре...

Comment: Дело в том, что учат в школе, не думать, а думать шаблонно. Но если ровняться на шаблон, то следующее поколение не поймет даже текущего шаблона. Это же очевидная вещь. И установка на шаблон - это пол беды, но принятие шаблона и шаблонности - это скорее тотальная ошибка руководства, которая приведет к деградации образования вообще. Не сейчас, а через пару поколений. Хотя даже сейчас это уже очевидно. Я чувствую себя гением порой, хотя по русскому языку у меня была 2) а по литературе 3.

Comment: @Буратино
  Меня это тоже беспокоит... Мне почему-то в детстве очень нравился "Золотой осел", но теперь уже не помню почему)) Сейчас как? Если не хочешь учиться по общему шаблону, есть две возможности: не учиться вовсе или учиться в спецшколах, в онлайн-школах и т.д. Если, конечно,у родителей есть деньги. А у меня есть практический вопрос на шаблонную тему. А если я скажу так: Книга дарит нам крылья для полета нашей фантазии. Книга будет метафорой?

Comment: @Sharon Я думаю, это будет тавтология, так как крылья не для плавания дарят). Тут точное не олицетворение, так как книга не конкретизирована, а значит не может быть персонифицирована. Тут книга - это чтение книг. Дарит - переносное значение, метафора, а крылья для полета - это аллегория, точнее могла ей быть, так как крылья - символ полета, а полет это тоже символ, но чего, возвышения над мирской суетой? Но тайна раскрыта, поэтому аллегория не аллегория. Но опять же, это как взвешивать на продуктовых весах крупицы сахара. Метафора не обязательно одно слово, это вырожденная метафора.

Comment: Фишка метафоры, что её можно воспринимать как буквально, формально, то это будет скорее аллегория, символизм. Но метафора доаллегорична. Фишка метафоры, что её можно воспринимать вне символики, но из-за стремление учиться, обучаться, подражать, воспринимать, познавать мир через метафору, она становится универсальным ключом. Метафора - это способ глядеть на мир не как на цель или средство, а как на нечто любопытное, метафора, если и провоцирует, то фантазию, это ключ для фантазии. Но при этом, метафору можно воспринимать буквально, она от этого не становится менее правдивой.

Comment: Эта книга зачитана до дыр - это метафора, но при этом, книга явно не нова, потрепана, но при этом к ней относились бережно, почему? Эта книга ценна, ценна своим содержанием, эта книга дорога своему владельцу, именно поэтому он обращается к ней снова и снова, он хочет её "съесть", проглотить целиком, при этом сохранив... Это метафора, но она буквальна. Почему рассказы животные у Эзопа это метафора? Потому что они буквальны, они живут точно такой же жизнью, почти всегда, вне человеческих чаяний и человеческих штампов.

Comment: лиса хитра умна, но она не символ лжи, муравей трудолюбив, но он действительно таков, если кто и хитер, то это осел(это же из Апулея), хотя его хитрости слишком очевидны, почему? Потому что он не думает о высоком, его мысли о том, чтобы получить выгоду сейчас, чтобы уклониться от труда сейчас, и это его подводит, если он думал немного вперед, если бы он мог думать чуть чуть вперед - он был бы рассуждать и действовать не хуже умнейшего человека. Видит ли человек в осле осла? Нет. Он видит себя, своё отражение.

Comment: И это самоотражение и дает человеку познать себя - отделить животное от человека, внутри себя без отчуждения внутренней сущности, внутренней половины, пусть я осёл, но это не мешает мне быть человеком. И видеть мир не только через осла, но и через человека. И человек и осел в одном лице. И теперь можно говорить о символике осла, животного и тп в произведениях, потому что понятно, что ноги растут из метафоры. С другой стороны метафора не разрушает понятие. Муравей, хоть и трудолюбив, он скуп на чувства и тут дилемма, он не творческий, хотя трудолюбивый, слишком трудолюбивый,  а цикада слишком..

Comment: То есть метафора создает и усложняет понятия, обобщает их. А в современном мире метафоры не много, потому что все предельно конкретно: деньги мерило человеческого успеха, а успешность определяет качество жизни, а качество жизни сводится к тому, что человек может позволить себе съесть на ужин или куда поехать на отдых. Почему человек едет куда-то на отдых? Потому что он устает от быта, от собственного бытия, потому что  это бытие ему чуждо. Он знает все, себя не зная и себя избегая.

Comment: Человек избегая себя играет роли, олицетворяет сущности, но не себя, изображает, а не воображает. Метафора - это воображение, но не imagination - не плоские картинки ассоциаций, не имидж, а что-то более связанное и самостоятельное.

Comment: Спасибо! Класс! У вас такая интересная и необычная философия. Все скопировала, буду изучать и постигать)

Comment: @Sharon с Лессингом промахнулся, все-таки это 18 век) но тем не менее спор из-за басен в прозе и стихах имел место быть.